# How to set a custom resolution with nvidia drivers installed?

Tags: nvidia, resolution

Frist: I'm new to linux. I'm using debian 9.1.0 lxde 64 bits.

I gave up trying to change the resolution when I got black screen at the login screen, just the terminal mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) works. I tried the commom `cvt -> xrandr --newmode -> xrandr --addmode -> xrandr output` I get an error at the `addmode` step, and tried with `gft` too, but the same. also tried to edit the xorg.conf file, it was when I got this issue. I actually have access to my ext4 partition throuth windows 10 (using ExtFS).
My driver version is 384.69, my gpu is gtx 750ti, my monitor is XP911AW. I got this data from it's EDID (all from the same file, at one run):

```
DumpEDID v1.06
Copyright (c) 2006 - 2017 Nir Sofer
Web site: http://www.nirsoft.net
```

---

```
Active                   : No
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\PEB038F\1&8713bca&0&UID0
Monitor Name             : XP911AW
Serial Number            : 0708500665431
Manufacture Week         : 37 / 2007
ManufacturerID           : 41536 (0xA240)
ProductID                : 911 (0x038F)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 16843009 (0x01010101)
EDID Version             : 1.3
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Vertical Frequency       : 56 - 76 Hz
Horizontal Frequency     : 30 - 81 KHz
Maximum Image Size       : 41 X 26 cm (19.1 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 1440 X 900
Support Standby Mode     : Yes
Support Suspend Mode     : Yes
Support Low-Power Mode   : Yes
Support Default GTF      : No
Digital                  : No
Supported Display Modes  :
 720 X  400  70 Hz
 640 X  480  60 Hz
 640 X  480  72 Hz
 640 X  480  75 Hz
 800 X  600  56 Hz
 800 X  600  60 Hz
 800 X  600  72 Hz
 800 X  600  75 Hz
1024 X  768  60 Hz
1024 X  768  70 Hz
1024 X  768  75 Hz
1280 X  960  60 Hz
1280 X  960  75 Hz
1440 X  900  60 Hz
1440 X  900  75 Hz
1280 X 1024  60 Hz
1280 X 1024  75 Hz
```

---

---

```
Active                   : No
Registry Key             : DISPLAY\PEB038F\4&2c0f5421&0&UID16843008
Monitor Name             : XP911AW
Serial Number            : 0708500665431
Manufacture Week         : 37 / 2007
ManufacturerID           : 41536 (0xA240)
ProductID                : 911 (0x038F)
Serial Number (Numeric)  : 16843009 (0x01010101)
EDID Version             : 1.3
Display Gamma            : 2.20
Vertical Frequency       : 56 - 76 Hz
Horizontal Frequency     : 30 - 81 KHz
Maximum Image Size       : 41 X 26 cm (19.1 Inch)
Maximum Resolution       : 1440 X 900
Support Standby Mode     : Yes
Support Suspend Mode     : Yes
Support Low-Power Mode   : Yes
Support Default GTF      : No
Digital                  : No
Supported Display Modes  :
 720 X  400  70 Hz
 640 X  480  60 Hz
 640 X  480  72 Hz
 640 X  480  75 Hz
 800 X  600  56 Hz
 800 X  600  60 Hz
 800 X  600  72 Hz
 800 X  600  75 Hz
1024 X  768  60 Hz
1024 X  768  70 Hz
1024 X  768  75 Hz
1280 X  960  60 Hz
1280 X  960  75 Hz
1440 X  900  60 Hz
1440 X  900  75 Hz
1280 X 1024  60 Hz
1280 X 1024  75 Hz
```

---

Just a little off-topic, do you know if this driver (downloaded from geforce.com, which is a .run file) includes cuda too?

EDIT: I tried to edit the xorg.conf file from windows, no sucess, and now the screen don't become black anymore, but don't start the graphical interface at all. I still can use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Попробуй install nvidia-current , но сначала удали то что поставил. Незн точно какой в дебе пакетный менеджер. Для бубунты такая комманда `apt install nvidia-current`

Comment: try install `nvidia-current` from standart reps.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall the driver alredy installed? The problem looks like a xorg.conf problem, but I changed this config to try change the resolution to 1440x900@75hz. What's the difference between the official driver and the one from ``apt install nvidia-current``? Does this at least resets the current config files? Does cuda works with this driver?

Comment: the ``apt install nvidia-current`` returned something like "no candidates available to install".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, I could solve my problem. Here is how:

at the login screen, I entered in the terminal mode and typed:

1. `cvt 1440 900 75` (my wanted resolutions and refresh rate, and copied the modeline string)
2. `su`
3. `nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
   Here I updated my refresh rates and added the entire modeline string.

   ```
   Section "Monitor"
       Identifier     "Monitor0"
       VendorName     "Unknown"
       ModelName      "Unknown"
       HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
       VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
       Modeline "1440x900_75.00" 136.75 1440 1536 1688 1936 900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync
       Option         "DPMS"
   EndSection
   ```